# UINavigationController how to set title and etc in children views

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My app structure:

firstView: `UIViewController` with `UINavigationController` --  secondView `UITabBarController` with several `UIViewControllers`

start app, firstView:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let vc  = ViewController()
    let navContr = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

    self.window? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window?.rootViewController = navContr
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

In firtView I click button to open secondView:

```
let vc = MyTabController()  // my UITabBarController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

start secondView:

```
class MyTabController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let gen = MyViewController()
        let tabGen = UITabBarItem()
        gen.tabBarItem = tabGen
        tabGen.image = UIImage(named: "general")
        tabGen.title = "Все вопросы" 
        viewControllers = [gen]
        ....
    }
```

In my `secondView` I want set Title, set `UISearchControlleer` in every tab. But if I write in `ViewController`

`navigationItem.title = "myTitle"`  nothing changes. I see button **"Back"** only.

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYGyS.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Set title like this in** `viewDidLoad()` **Method**

```
self.title = "Your Title"
```

Comment: @Joe You need to add this in First ViewController so it will be displayed on the second view controller's back button after pushed.

Comment: do not quite understand. In my viewControlers in MyTabViewControlers  I don get access to navigationController. Its nill.  If I add  "self.title = "Your Title""  in didLoad() nothing changes.

Comment: @Joe So you need to embed Your every TabviewController with navigation Controller from Storyboard and if you Don't need display navigation bar in table view Controller then hide it and set title.

Comment: I dont use storyboard. it seems decided.  added  tabBarController?.title in ViewControllers

Comment: @Joe If you Get the navigationController nil then how can push it to Second View Controller ?

Comment: you first need to embed your first Vc in an UINavigationController, then you will have the navigationController in the first view controller

Comment: @ Nikunj Kumbhani  I get nill in SecondControllers(UITabViewController) in method didLoad  in viewcontrolers   when call  self.navigationController